# Selecting rows where a column changes by more than a threshold

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing three columns, where the first is an ID, the second denotes a year and the third column is the value associated with the ID in that year:

```
df.in <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                    "yr"=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2010, 2001,2002,2003,2006,2008,2009, 2001, 2002,2003,2004,2005,2007,2009),
                    "val"=c(5,6,7,8,10, 1,2,3,6,8,10, 1,2,3,4,5,7,9))
```

I'd like to remove rows where the year has a gap with the previous year which is larger than 1. In other words, I want to keep only those rows in the data where the years follow each other in increments of 1:

```
df.out <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3),
                     "yr"=c(2005,2006,2007,2008, 2001,2002,2003,2001, 2002,2003,2004,2005),
                     "val"=c(5,6,7,8, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4,5))
```

Is there a way to do this in R using `dplyr`? If possible, I'd like a dataframe containing all discarded years as well:

```
df.discard <- data.frame("id"=c(1, 2,2, 3,3),
                         "yr"=c(2010, 2006, 2008,2009, 2007,2009),
                         "val"=c(10, 6, 8,10, 7,9))
```

Comment: why is row no. 9 in the output?

Comment: @akrun That is a typo by me, sorry

Comment: @N08 Did the answer help your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering out based on your rule with `lag`

```
df.in %>% filter(val - lag(val) > 1)
```

Based on @Sotos and @akrun, changing the code from using `val` to `yr`:

```
df.in <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                    "yr"=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2010, 2001,2002,2003,2006,2008,2010, 2001, 2002,2003,2004,2005,2007,2009),
                    "val"=c(5,6,7,8,10, 1,2,3,6,8,10, 1,2,3,4,5,7,9))

df.out <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3),
                     "yr"=c(2005,2006,2007,2008, 2001,2002,2003,2006,2001, 2002,2003,2004,2005),
                     "val"=c(5,6,7,8, 1,2,3,6, 1,2,3,4,5))


#output

df.out <- df.in %>% group_by(id) %>% filter((yr - lag(yr, default = yr[1]) <= 1))

df.out

#ignored

df.ignored <- df.in %>% group_by(id) %>% filter((yr - lag(yr, default = yr[1]) > 1))

df.ignored
```

Output:

```
> df.out
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups: id [3]
      id    yr   val
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1.00  2005  5.00
 2  1.00  2006  6.00
 3  1.00  2007  7.00
 4  1.00  2008  8.00
 5  2.00  2001  1.00
 6  2.00  2002  2.00
 7  2.00  2003  3.00
 8  3.00  2001  1.00
 9  3.00  2002  2.00
10  3.00  2003  3.00
11  3.00  2004  4.00
12  3.00  2005  5.00
> df.ignored
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: id [3]
     id    yr   val
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.00  2010 10.0 
2  2.00  2006  6.00
3  2.00  2008  8.00
4  2.00  2010 10.0 
5  3.00  2007  7.00
6  3.00  2009  9.00
```

Comment: @Sotos No it will miss the first row.  It would be `df.in %>% filter(val - lag(val, default = val[1]) <= 1)`

Comment: @akrun you are correct. It wasn't notable because he didn't group_by(id).

Comment: @Sotos Also, I think the OP mentioned about the `yr` instead of `val`.  Probably the `val` is the last character of `year` based on the data

Comment: @akrun True. I think val is just the part after (20**) which is there to make the `diff` more obvious.

Comment: Sorry I was out for lunch. @akrun should i change the code with yr instead of val?

Comment: @akrun This doesn't seem to be general enough. In the OP I made a changed (2010 of ID==2 to 2009), and in this case the output  shouldn't contain either 2008 nor 2009 - but using this example 2009 is retained. I updated the examples in the OP

Comment: @N08 You've updated the desired output also in the questions?

Comment: @N08 What is the logic behind having 1-2008-8 in output and also discard?

Comment: @amrrs Sorry, that was my error - it's not supposed to be there. I deleted it now

Comment: @N08 And why don't you have 2-2006 in your discard - doesn't it appear after 2003 which means it should be discarded?

Comment: @amrrs Exactly right, I just updated it the second you wrote. Sorry -- it should be correct now

Comment: @N08 the same code works fine for me, can you point out the case which is wrong?

Comment: @N08 And the reason 2009 comes in the output is because the preceding year is 2008, so ideally based on your logic it should come in the output.