# How can I create a new variable which identifies rows where another variable changes sign?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a question regarding data preparation. I have the following data set (in long format; one row per measurement point, therefore several rows per person):

```
dd <- read.table(text=
"ID    time
1      -4
1      -3
1      -2
1      -1
1       0
1       1
2      -3
2      -1
2       2
2       3
2       4
3      -3
3      -2
3      -1
4      -1
4       1   
4       2
4       3
5       0
5       1
5       2
5       3
5       4", header=TRUE)
```

Now I would like to create a new variable that has a 1 in the row, in which a sign change on the time variable happens for the first time for this person, and a 0 in all other rows. If a person has only negative values on *time*, the should not be any 1 on the new variable. For a person that has only positive values on *time*, the first row should have a 1 on the new variable and all other rows should be coded with 0. For my example above the new data frame should look like this:

```
dd <- read.table(text=
"ID    time   new.var
1      -4     0
1      -3     0
1      -2     0
1      -1     0
1       0     1
1       1     0
2      -3     0
2      -1     0
2       2     1
2       3     0
2       4     0
3      -3     0  
3      -2     0
3      -1     0
4      -1     0
4       1     1  
4       2     0
4       3     0
5       0     1
5       1     0
5       2     0
5       3     0
5       4     0", header=TRUE)
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I thought about using dplyr and group_by, however I am pretty new to R and did not make it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45154687/8366499, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48378653/8366499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different operations you want done to create `new.var`, so you need to do them in 2 steps. I'll break this into 2 separate `mutate` calls for simplicity, but you can put both of them into the same `mutate`

First, we group by ID and then find the rows where the sign changes. We need to use `time >= 0` instead of `sign` as recommended in this answer: [R identifying a row prior to a change in sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033696/r-identifying-a-row-prior-to-a-change-in-sign) because you want a sign change to be counted only when going from -1 <-> 0, not from 0 <-> 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
dd2 <- dd %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(new.var = as.numeric((time >= 0) != (lag(time) >= 0)))

dd2
# A tibble: 23 x 3
# Groups:   ID [5]
      ID  time new.var
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     1    -4      NA
 2     1    -3       0
 3     1    -2       0
 4     1    -1       0
 5     1     0       1
 6     1     1       0
 7     2    -3      NA
 8     2    -1       0
 9     2     2       1
10     2     3       0
# … with 13 more rows
```

Then we use `case_when` to modify the first row based on your desired rules. Due to the way `lag` works, the first row will always have `NA` (since there is no previous row to look at) which makes it a good way to pick out that first row to change it based on the `time` values in that group:

```
dd3 <- dd2 %>%
    mutate(new.var = case_when(
               !is.na(new.var) ~ new.var,
               all(time >= 0) ~ 1,
               TRUE ~ 0)
    )

print(dd3, n = 100) #n=100 because tibbles are truncated to 10 rows by print

# A tibble: 23 x 3
# Groups:   ID [5]
      ID  time new.var
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     1    -4       0
 2     1    -3       0
 3     1    -2       0
 4     1    -1       0
 5     1     0       1
 6     1     1       0
 7     2    -3       0
 8     2    -1       0
 9     2     2       1
10     2     3       0
11     2     4       0
12     3    -3       0
13     3    -2       0
14     3    -1       0
15     4    -1       0
16     4     1       1
17     4     2       0
18     4     3       0
19     5     0       1
20     5     1       0
21     5     2       0
22     5     3       0
23     5     4       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% left_join(dd %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(index=min(which(time>=0)))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new.var=ifelse(row_number(ID)==index,1,0)) %>% select(-index)-> DF

# A tibble: 23 x 3
# Groups:   ID [5]
      ID  time new.var
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     1    -4       0
 2     1    -3       0
 3     1    -2       0
 4     1    -1       0
 5     1     0       1
 6     1     1       0
 7     2    -3       0
 8     2    -1       0
 9     2     2       1
10     2     3       0
```

Comment: Hoping this can help!

Answer (score 0):

The following `ave` instruction does what the question asks for.

```
dd$new.var <- with(dd, ave(time, ID, FUN = function(x){
  y <- integer(length(x))
  if(any(x >= 0)) y[which.max(x[1]*x <= 0)] <- 1L
  y
}))

dd
#   ID time new.var
#1   1   -4       0
#2   1   -3       0
#3   1   -2       0
#4   1   -1       0
#5   1    0       1
#6   1    1       0
#7   2   -3       0
#8   2   -1       0
#9   2    2       1
#10  2    3       0
#11  2    4       0
#12  3   -3       0
#13  3   -2       0
#14  3   -1       0
#15  4   -1       0
#16  4    1       1
#17  4    2       0
#18  4    3       0
#19  5    0       1
#20  5    1       0
#21  5    2       0
#22  5    3       0
#23  5    4       0
```

If the expected output is renamed `dd2` then

```
identical(dd, dd2)
#[1] TRUE
```